# Apache beam python sdk failing with IllegalArgumentException

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FakeKeyedWorkItemCoder only works with KeyedWorkItemCoder or KvCoder; was: class org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.LengthPrefixCoder
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.WindmillKeyedWorkItem$FakeKeyedWorkItemCoder.<init>(WindmillKeyedWorkItem.java:211)
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.TimerOrElement$TimerOrElementCoder.<init>(TimerOrElement.java:53)
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.TimerOrElement$TimerOrElementCoder.of(TimerOrElement.java:57)
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.TimerOrElement$TimerOrElementCloudObjectTranslator.fromCloudObject(TimerOrElement.java:85)
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.TimerOrElement$TimerOrElementCloudObjectTranslator.fromCloudObject(TimerOrElement.java:67)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.CloudObjects.coderFromCloudObject(CloudObjects.java:87)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.CloudObjectTranslators.getComponents(CloudObjectTranslators.java:71)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.CloudObjectTranslators.access$100(CloudObjectTranslators.java:51)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.CloudObjectTranslators$6.fromCloudObject(CloudObjectTranslators.java:248)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.CloudObjectTranslators$6.fromCloudObject(CloudObjectTranslators.java:237)
    org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.util.CloudObjects.coderFromCloudObject(CloudObjects.java:87)
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BeamFnMapTaskExecutorFactory$5.typedApply(BeamFnMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:593)
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BeamFnMapTaskExecutorFactory$5.typedApply(BeamFnMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:587)
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks$TypeSafeNodeFunction.apply(Networks.java:63)
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks$TypeSafeNodeFunction.apply(Networks.java:50)
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.graph.Networks.replaceDirectedNetworkNodes(Networks.java:87)
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.BeamFnMapTaskExecutorFactory.create(BeamFnMapTaskExecutorFactory.java:136)
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1143)
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:136)
    com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:966)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Error trace above,
The pipeline works fine on my local machine but breaks on dataflow runner with the above error, for which I could not find any relevant information anywhere.
Details: Reading from Pubsub -> 120 seconds windowing -> group by key -> insert to bigquery

Answer (score 0):

The error was because the key,value in pcoll was coming from a different class. Although I was returning string, it was still giving the error.
Adding a function in same class as the pipeline to take input before groupbykey, and output the same element worked.